# GitHub action stalls on setup-r-dependencies@v2

Tags: r, github-actions, pak

This is cross posted on the [RStudio Community site](https://community.rstudio.com/t/github-action-stalls-on-setup-r-dependencies-v2/147278). I am using `r-lib/setup-r-dependencies@v2` for a bookdown project on GitHub action. However, the job is stalling when pak tries to create a lock file. Here is an [example run](https://github.com/atlas-aai/ncdb-example/actions/runs/3049563776/jobs/4915758918) , and here is the [workflow](https://github.com/atlas-aai/ncdb-example/blob/main/.github/workflows/bookdown.yml).

As you can see, eventually the job just times out.

[image: screenshot of the dependency resolution step failing after nearly 6 hours of run time]

The issue seems similar to [this post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/pak-lockfile-creation-within-github-action-hangs-forever/125813). The solution there was to use the most current RSPM, but I believe that is already what I am using (I don't specify anything different in the workflow).

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

**Edit**: Here is the full yaml code for the workflow (linked above)

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
  workflow_dispatch:

name: bookdown

jobs:
  bookdown:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Only restrict concurrency for non-PR jobs
    concurrency:
      group: pkgdown-${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' || github.run_id }}
    env:
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-pandoc@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@v2
        with:
          use-public-rspm: true

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r-dependencies@v2
        with:
          cache-version: 1

      - name: Cache bookdown results
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: _bookdown_files
          key: bookdown-${{ hashFiles('**/*Rmd') }}
          restore-keys: bookdown-

      - name: Build site
        run: bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", quiet = TRUE)
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Deploy to GitHub pages 
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.4
        with:
          branch: gh-pages
          folder: _book
```

Comment: Can you post what is in the code call?

Comment: Added the full yaml for the workflow to the post. Thanks!